# Symfony2 FOSElastica and Elasticsearch

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm using this configuration for elasticsearch powered search feature. Now when i populate indexes the search function works fine and i get desired results. But, after some time(couple of hours) the search stops working and results are plain wrong. The application uses cron jobs to update entities every 15 minutes noted in the config(and other data). Am i supposed to update indexes as entities update and if so how do i do it? Some of them are related like team and players.

I'm using FOSElasticaBundle 3.0.

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    kladise:
        finder: ~
        types:
            blogs:
                mappings:
                    title: ~
                    shortContent: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            tips:
                mappings:
                    title: ~
                    shortContent: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\TipsterBundle\Entity\Tip
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            soccer_players:
                mappings:
                    firstName: ~
                    lastName: ~
                    name: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\SoccerBundle\Entity\People
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            soccer_teams:
                mappings:
                    clubName: ~
                    shortName: ~
                    officialName: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\SoccerBundle\Entity\Team
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            hockey_players:
                mappings:
                    firstName: ~
                    lastName: ~
                    name: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\HockeyBundle\Entity\People
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            hockey_teams:
                mappings:
                    clubName: ~
                    shortName: ~
                    officialName: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\HockeyBundle\Entity\Team
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            handball_players:
                mappings:
                    firstName: ~
                    lastName: ~
                    name: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\HandballBundle\Entity\People
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            handball_teams:
                mappings:
                    clubName: ~
                    shortName: ~
                    officialName: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\HandballBundle\Entity\Team
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            basketball_players:
                mappings:
                    firstName: ~
                    lastName: ~
                    name: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\BasketballBundle\Entity\People
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~

            basketball_teams:
                mappings:
                    clubName: ~
                    shortName: ~
                    officialName: ~

                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model: Acme\BasketballBundle\Entity\Team
                    provider: ~
                    listener: ~
                    finder: ~
```

Comment: if you manually re-index you should disable the listener, that auto updates the index if entity is persisted

Comment: I'm not manually reindexing. Should i, or there is a way to automatically update them when entity updates?